# Swift: How to cast error to generic struct

Tags: swift, generics

I am being passed an Error at runtime. This error is actually a generic struct. I need to cast the error to this struct so I can get its details. How can I do this?

Code Example:

```
protocol MinorErrorType: Error {}
struct MajorError<T: MinorErrorType>: Error {
    let minorError: T
}
enum SomeMinorError: MinorErrorType {
    case error
}

func getName(_ error: Error) -> String {
    "Some Error"
}
func getName<T: MinorErrorType>(_ error: MajorError<T>) -> String {
    "MajorError"
}

func printName(_ error: Error) {
    print(getName(error))
}

let error = MajorError<SomeMinorError>(minorError: .error)
printName(error)

// output: 
// Some Error
```

You can see in the above code the generic getName is not called. If there is a solution where I only need to modify func printName that would be awesome.

Update: In production, I want to use this pattern for logging. I want a logger to be passed an error and be able to log MajorError's. I do not want to have to cast to `MajorError<SomeMinorError>` in getName as that would mean I would need to cast for all new implementations of MinorErrorType. This would make my logger need to know about too much information.

In the meantime, I used type erasure ([here is a great article on the subject)](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/different-flavors-of-type-erasure-in-swift/)

```
protocol MajorErrorType: Error {
    func eraseToAnyMajorError() -> AnyMajorError
}
enum AnyMajorError {
    case majorError(MinorErrorType)
}

protocol MinorErrorType: Error {}
struct MajorError<T: MinorErrorType>: Error {
    let minorError: T
    func eraseToAnyMajorError() -> AnyMajorError {
        .majorError(minorError)
    }
}

...

func printName(_ error: Error) {
    if let majorError = (error as? MajorErrorType)?.eraseToAnyMajorError() {
        print(getName(majorError))
    else {
        print(getName(error))
    }
}
```

This lets the rest of my code use the generic structs (fun) and my logger in the dark about other error types.

Comment: What’s the purpose of a protocol that has no requirements? Btw Error has no requirement either.

Comment: Get rid of that protocol, declare two enumerations, one for each error `enum MajorError: Error {`
    `case major`
`}` and  
`enum MinorError: Error {`
    `case minor`
`}` then create a single method that takes a generic Error and switch the error `func getName(_ error: Error) -> String {`
    `witch error {`
    `case let error as MajorError: return error.rawValue`
    `case let error as MinorError: return error.rawValue`
    `default: return "generic Error"`
    `}`
`}` now you can simply declare your `let error: MinorError = .minor` and get its name 
`getName(error)`

Comment: Leo, In production this protocol is not empty. However, in this case, it adds a requirement that MiniorError needs to conform to.

Comment: Leo, the issue with the approach provided in your second answer means that my getName method needs to know all the possible errors that are created.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but I would use proper *encapsulation* to help with this issue. I.e. define `getName` as a function of your struct, enum, etc., so you can call it on appropriate type:

```
protocol MinorErrorType: Error {}

extension Error {

    func getName() -> String {
        "Some Error in extension"
    }
}

struct MajorError<T: MinorErrorType>: Error {
    let minorError: T

    func getName() -> String {
        "MajorError in struct"
    }
}
enum SomeMinorError: MinorErrorType {
    case error
}
```

Now inside `printError` you can control what to call:

```
func printName(_ error: Error) {

    if let majorError = error as? MajorError<SomeMinorError> {
        print(majorError.getName())
    } else {
        print(error.getName())
    }
}
```

So if you call

```
let error = MajorError<SomeMinorError>(minorError: .error)
printName(error) // prints MajorError in struct
```

But you don't need `printName` function with it's casting at all: you can call `getName()`, and it will call `getName` from Error extension only if nothing else is defined:

```
let error = MajorError<SomeMinorError>(minorError: .error)
let smthElse = NSError(domain: "s", code: 123, userInfo: nil)
print(error.getName()) // prints MajorError in struct as before
print(smthElse.getName()) // prints Some Error in extension
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do not want to add the getName method to the protocol or enums as this breaks encapsulation. You can imagine in production there would be much more than just getName and I would like to keep it to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to switch your error. No need to create a another method:

```
func getName(_ error: Error) -> String {
    switch error {
    case is MajorError<SomeMinorError>: return "MajorError"
    default: return "Some Error"
    }
}
```

To access your error properties you can cast the error instead of checking its type:

```
func getName(_ error: Error) -> String {
    switch error {
    case let error as MajorError<SomeMinorError>:
        return "\(error.minorError)"
    default: return "Some Error"
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
protocol MinorErrorType: Error {}

struct MajorError<T: MinorErrorType>: Error {
    let minorError: T
}
enum SomeMinorError: MinorErrorType {
    case minor
}

func getName(_ error: Error) -> String {
    switch error {
    case let error as MajorError<SomeMinorError>:
        return "\(error.minorError)"
    default: return "Some Error"
    }
}

let error = MajorError<SomeMinorError>(minorError: .minor)
print(getName(error))  // "minor\n"
```

You can also give your error a `RawValue`:

```
enum SomeMinorError: String, MinorErrorType {
    case minor
}

func getName(_ error: Error) -> String {
    switch error {
    case let error as MajorError<SomeMinorError>:
        return error.minorError.rawValue
    default: return "Some Error"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response. The issue with my production code is that I do not want it to know about the underlying errors (in the example SomeMinorError). I would like to be able to add new MinorErrorTypes and not need to update the getName method each time. You can imagine over time this can become burdensome.